# Password protecting internally through URL and AJAX?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, url

At my old company we had an internal website setup to only let you view it if you had the password at the end of your URL, I assume that is using AJAX but I'm not quite sure, and even if it was I'm not sure how to code it.

The URL would look something like this internal.mysite/secretpanel?pass=superman, and if you typed in anything but superman it redirects you to the incorrect pass page.

My question is how do I check a URL for a password and redirect to a "incorrect password" page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you described does not sound like AJAX and also is a horribly insecure system (even as far as internal systems go).

If you are using PHP, you might want to take a look at sessions rather than passing a password in as a portion of the query string in your URL. A simple implementation of this would be to have a login page that checks values posted from a form before redirecting you to a page containing your secrets.

**login.php**

```
 session_start();
 if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))
 {
     // Check to see if the username and password is correct
     if (user_is_valid_user($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])
     {
         $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;

         // Redirect to your secret page
         header("Location: http://mysite.com/secret.php");
     }
 }
 else
 {
     // Display the login form
     echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"login.php\">";
     echo "   <input type=\"input\" name=\"username\" />";
     echo "   <input type=\"password\" name=\"password\" />";
     echo "   <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Login\" />";
     echo "</form>";
 }
```

**secret.php**

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['logged_in']))
{
     // Redirect to the login page since user is not logged in
     header("Location: http://mysite.com/login.php");
}

// Display your secret content here
```

Comment: I appreciate everyones concern for security, and this is helpful, but I am more interested in the original question of a URL password, its not for security, its for speed first, security last.

Comment: You can check by using if ($_GET['password'] != "superman") { header("Location: someotherpage.com"); }

Comment: That said, the reason that we are recommending the security changes, is that you might as not have security at all with the current scheme.

Answer (score 1):

1. I hope you're not using that for anything secure. Passwords in URLs instead of as POST data aren't the best idea.
2. Nope, that's not AJAX.
3. You'd want to do this on the server side, not the client side.

Comment: So if I was using PHP how would I accomplish something like this?

Comment: And no its not for anything secure, I just want to keep a tool from being messed with inhouse by people not in the department.

Answer (score 0):

Use $_GET['password'] (or any name you wish to use as your "password" variable name). Assign it to a variable or compare it directly with the server-saved variable. If you're not concerned about security, no need to cleanse it either, although ceejayoz is right, if you want security, use posted variables, that way nobody can "happen to glance down and see" the url password.